# Django is there an 'empty' with 'for' loop having a 'if' condition?

Tags: django-templates, django-2.2

I have this:

```
{% for prop in props %}
   {% if prop.status == 'SOLD' %}
      {{ name }}
   {% endif %}
{% empty %}
   <li>No closed deals.</li>
{% endfor %}
```

and of course it doesn't do what I want, as far as an empty `if` loop.

Aside from just filtering the statuses into lists from the view, is there an `empty` for this kind of loop?  I tried setting a true/false using a `{% with sold=True %}`, but it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below, which would mean if a value is empty, False, or None it will evaluate to true:

```
{% if not prop.status %}
do something
{% endif %}
```

OR

use an else statement, which would catch all values that are not 'SOLD'

```
{% if prop.status == 'SOLD' %}
do stuff
{% else %}
do something else
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes, but then I will get an else for every iteration.  I'm looking for a count=0 type of after action.  The prop list will almost always have items, so there are going to be iterations from the other conditions (eg, == 'available', =='hold')

Comment: from your theorized example, you are expecting at times that the 'props' dictionary would sometimes be blank or empty.  but what you just stated was is it will not ever be empty.  if that's the case, you have to run conditions within the loop

Comment: Maybe it could be misunderstood.  If props were empty, the {% empty %} in my example would catch it. I was looking for something to catch the {% if %}, if it doesn't have any hits.  I'll just make it into multiple sets that empty can work with.